# regex to extract link from url

Tags: regex

```
x='http://example.bol.com/click/click?p=1&t=url&s=IDHERE&url=https://www.bol.com/nl/p/jbl-e55bt-draadloze-over-ear-koptelefoon-zwart/9200000064299118&f=TXL&name=/koptelefoon/'

x1='https://example.net/click/camref:IDhere/destination:https://www.mywebsite.com/product/138/sony-ps4.html&q=electronics'

x2='https://example.hn/clickbtn/camref:IDhere/creativeref:IDHERE/destination:https://www.coolblue.nl/product/465/sony-ps4-zwart'
```

my regex so far `https?:\/\/www.(?:mywebsite|coolblue|bol)\.(?:com|nl)(?:\/|\?).*?(?:\.html|\.php|\&)`

I have 2 small issues, how can I make so the patter doesn't include "&" (stops right before first &), and capture `x2` link

Comment: Try this: https?:\/\/www.(?:mywebsite|coolblue|bol)\.(?:com|nl)(?:\/|\?).*?(?=&|') I replaced the last part with a look ahead.

Comment: Of course it does, are you sure you copied correctly? Note, I removed the last part of your regex!

Comment: @PoulBak it works, you can post as answer, please explain what `(?=&|') ` do exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the changed regex:

```
https?:\/\/www.(?:mywebsite|coolblue|bol)\.(?:com|nl)(?:\/|\?).*?(?=&|')
```

I first removed the last part of your regex, since it's not needed.

I then added :

```
(?=&|')
```

This is a so called `positive look ahead`- starts with `(?=` and ends with `)`

What it does is that looks forward (to the right) to match what's in the parentes, here the `ampersand (&)` OR the `single quote (')`. However it does NOT add this match to the final regex match, it only 'looks'.

There is a lot of posts here on regex to lookup more info on 'positive look ahead'.

Comment: this will not work on a generic link such as https://example.net/click/camref:IDhere/destination:https://www.mywebsite.com/product/138/sony-ps4.html

Answer (score 0):

To get all the matches from the example data you might use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^&\s]*` to match any char except `&` or a whitespace char after matching `/` or `?`

```
https?:\/\/www\.(?:mywebsite|coolblue|bol)\.(?:com|nl)[\/?][^&\s]*
```

**Explanation**

- `https?:\/\/www\.` Match the protocol with an optional s and a mandatory `www.` part
- `(?:mywebsite|coolblue|bol)` Match one of the alternatives
- `\.(?:com|nl)` Match a dot (Note to escape the dot) and either com or nl
- `[/?]` Match either a `/` or `?`
- `[^&\s]*` Match 0 or more occurrences of any char except `&` or a whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k9jJbC/1)